# Using a nested loop to output distances C++

Tags: loops, vector

I have three vectors:

```
vector<string> city;
vector<int> x-coord;
vector<int> y-coord;
```

I want to output a table like so:

```
               [city(1)]      [city(2)]      [city(3)]       [city(n)]
[city(1)]     distance(1,1)  distance(2,1)  distance(3,1)  distance(n,1)
[city(2)]     distance(1,2)  distance(2,2)  distance(3,2)  distance(n,2)
[city(3)]     distance(1,3)  distance(2,3)  distance(3,3)  distance(n,3)
[city(n)]     distance(1,n)  distance(2,n)  distance(3,n)  distance(n,n)
```

I can output a multiplication table and I think I'd use the same style of loop.

So,

```
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int row, col;
for (row = 0; row < city.size(); row++) { 
for (col = 0; col < city.size(); col++) {
        int dist = sqrt(pow(x-coord.at(col+1)-x-coord.at(col),2) +
                    pow(y-coord.at(col+1) - y-coord.at(col),2));
        cout << dist; 
    }
cout << endl;
}
```

This is not giving me the desired output. Can anybody give me a hand?

#### Fix some code ...

Some bracket/parenthesis issues need fixing and indentation was poor:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int row, col;
for (row = 0; row < city.size()-1; row++) {
    cout << city.at(row);
    for (col = 0; col < city.size()-1; col++) {
        int dist = sqrt(    pow(x-coord.at(row) - x-coord.at(col), 2) + pow(y-coord.at(row) - y-coord.at(col), 2)     );
        cout << '\t' << dist;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

This now gives me list of cities as a row and a tabulated output of distances, but I want a top row with cities in too.

Answer (score 0):

I see your confusion.

First, row never gets used.  This would always compare the city to itself.

Second, from the looks of it, you should never have to add anything to any of the row/col indexes.

```
x-coord.at(row) - x-coord.at(col)
y-coord.at(row) - y-coord.at(col)
```

Third, your math is off

Distance is sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2).  You have sqrt(x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2)^2

Once you have this you can work out the formatting of your output.  I'd suggest storing your answers in another vector or other STD element and calling a function you create to do just that.

Comment: I've updated the post with some more code, is it possible to give me some more help, I've amended some of the issues you've given me?

Comment: Take a stab at formatting your output and I'll give you some help from there.  Your current code looks good.

As a suggestion I would recommend you don't use "using namespace".  The positive is it saves you a few keystrokes.  The negative is that it can really cause you issues when two namespaces contain an object with the same name such as osg::node with my::node.